# Bing Maps Infobox mouseout event issue: When using async call to change htmlContent

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I hope someone can help.

I am using Bing Maps (v8 - the latest), but when I create a custom Infobox and populate the contents using an async request, whether it be setTimeout/ajax - The mouseout event triggers even when the mouse cursor is (seemingly) within the boundaries of the infobox window. Even when I make small additional changes (DOM) to the infobox, the mouseout will trigger, so its not like the infobox is wiped in any way and is then refreshed .. unless M$ are doing something weird!

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'My Bing Maps Key',
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.60357, -122.32945)
});

var pushpins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(2, map.getBounds());
var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(pushpins[0].getLocation(), { 
htmlContent: '<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: #fff">{content}</div>', visible: false });

infobox.setMap(map);
for (var i = 0; i < pushpins.length; i++) {
    var pushpin = pushpins[i];
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'mouseover', openInfoboxForPin);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'mouseout', closeInfobox);
}
map.entities.push(pushpins);

function openInfoboxForPin(e) {
    //Make sure the infobox has metadata to display.
    if (e.target) {
        //Set the infobox options with the metadata of the pushpin.
        infobox.setOptions({
            location: e.target.getLocation(),
            visible: true,
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            infobox.setOptions({ htmlContent: pushpinFrameHTML.replace('{content}',html) });
        }, 400);
    }
}

function closeInfobox() {
    infobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
}
```

JSFIDDLE: [Fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/brownerg/1dptapr8/4/)

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in all the supported browsers and it is working 100% as expected. The mouse event should trigger as the infobox appears between the pushpin and the infobox, thus causing a mouseout event.

Comment: For me it's broken in `Chrome 59.0.3071.115`. Hover over the marker to make the infobox appear, and then immediately move your cursor over the infobox. After 400 milliseconds the `setHtmlContent` method is invoked, and then any mouse event over the infobox after that causes the infobox to close. I can fix it by applying the `mouseleave` event to the infobox, and thus as soon as the infobox appears you're mousing over it: https://jsfiddle.net/1dptapr8/5/ However that seems to be the wrong approach, since the code in the original Fiddle is per the official docs, minus the asynchronicity.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given browser version, mine is Chrome Version 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I can verify with Wildhoney I am getting the same sideaffect.